Make typescript believe that a class implements interface (implement an interface dynamically)
I'm a fan of Proxy but TS supporting dynamic props aren't so clear for me.
Can I somehow tell TS that a class implements an interface in a dynamic way like that?
I can of course cast to MyElement<T> & T (it works) in all return types (I plan a lot of chain methods), but that's boring.
Playground
class MyElement<T extends HTMLElement> implements T{
    elem: T;
    static create<T extends HTMLElement>(elem: T){
        return new MyElement(elem);
    }
    constructor(elem: T){
        this.elem = elem;
        const self = this;
        return new Proxy(self, {
            get(_, prop){
                if(prop in self){
                    return self[prop as keyof typeof self];
                }
                return self.elem[prop as keyof T];
            }
        });
    }
    find<E extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>(selector: string){
        return new MyElement<E>(this.elem.querySelector(selector)!) as E & MyElement<E>;
    }
}

const body = MyElement.create<HTMLBodyElement>(document.body as HTMLBodyElement);
console.log(body.find('div').tagName);


What's the point of creating a class if its constructor returns a Proxy object anyway?

@RobbyCornelissen Proxy is exactly for that pattern. I can extends any html element dynamically with it. And it doesn't matter where it is. I can put the proxy in the static create(). The problem how to implement an interface dynamically

@AlexanderNenashev Why not just make it a function createElementProxy that takes an element and returns the Proxy? Playground

@DustInComp i can easily add methods/props to a class and avoid a mess in the proxy, proxy is just for checking whether a prop exist in the class or in the element and dispatch the prop accordingly

So the idea is to have the proxy access class properties/methods?

@RobbyCornelissen i've extends the question

@AlexanderNenashev MyElement.create<T> returns a Proxy<T>, not a MyElement<T>. You shouldn't be able to use it as a MyElement, e.g. call find on it, hence the type error.

You don't have to cast in all return types if you make your create() method return a MyElement<T> & T. Then make your constructor private to force the use of the factory method.

@RobbyCornelissen i need to cast return values in all chanable methods...

Not if you use your create() method instead of your constructor in your functions.

@RobbyCornelissen have of methods would return this

There's no direct way to do this with a class declaration. The closest you can get is to use a type assertion to tell TS that the MyElement constructor has the relevant type. As shown in this playground link. That might or might not suffice, depending on use cases. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?
